# Durandal HTML Samples Zip is SLOW

Tags: durandal

I'm trying to play with the Durandle HTML Samples Zip from their website.  For some reason, each time I try to navigate to a new tab it takes a noticeable amount of time to make the transition (1-2 seconds).  Why would this be?  I don't think its a network download thing because I'm running locally.

Answer (score 1):

It is the time it needs for the transition you can deactivate it by removing transition in `shell.html` i think.

```
<div class="page-host" data-bind="router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="page-host" data-bind="router: {cacheViews:true }"></div>
```

And i think 1sec is not a big deal.

you may want to set `cacheViews:false`